# Angular .filter() not working on JSON response

Tags: json, angular

From what I can tell, the .filter() method does not work on the response returned from .json() **when there is only 1 single object in the return value**. I am not sure how to go about dealing with this issue.

```
getFavorites() {
const userId = this.authService.getActiveUser().uid;
return this.http.get(this.databaseAddress + userId + '.json')
  .map(
    (response: Response) => {
    return response.json();
    })
  .do(
    (data) => {
      if(data) {
        this.favorites = data;
      }else {
        this.favorites = [];
      }
    })
```

}

```
this.favoritesService.getFavorites()
    .subscribe(
      (list: Recipe[]) => {
        if(list) {
          this.favoriteRecipes = list.filter(
            item => item !== null
          );
        } else {
          this.favoriteRecipes = [];
        }
      }
    );
```

Error returned:

```
ERROR TypeError: list.filter is not a function
```

Comment: That’s nothing to do with Angular. Filter is a JS array method; if you don’t have an array, you can’t use it.

Comment: any ways to go around this?

Comment: create an empty array and fill it up iterating json responded in map function before subscribe. So you can return json array every time.

Answer (score 0):

In case of no data returned from API, your response will be `null`/`empty`. And `filter` operation only works on Array type. Consider returning `[]` empty array from `map` operator.

```
getFavorites() {
const userId = this.authService.getActiveUser().uid;
return this.http.get(this.databaseAddress + userId + '.json')
  .map(
    (response: Response) => {
        return response.json() || []; // return blank [] if data is null or empty
    })
  .do(
    (data) => {
      if(data) {
        this.favorites = data;
      }else {
        this.favorites = [];
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: hi, as you can see I am already handling thiis situation in the 2nd block of code I provided. The issue here is not when response is null/empty, issue is when the response only has 1 object in it.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the issue here is not when response is null/empty, issue is when the response only has 1 object in it.

Just append whatever result you have to an empty array, and you are done...

```
getFavorites() {
const userId = this.authService.getActiveUser().uid;
return this.http.get(this.databaseAddress + userId + '.json')
  .map(
    (response: Response) => {
    return response.json();
    })
  .do(
    (data) => {
      if(data) {
        this.favorites = [].push(data);
      }else {
        this.favorites = [];
      }
    })
```